# Sorting a Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>> by the value of the inner Dictionary value using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5

I can't seem to wrap my head around this one. I need to sort a Dictionary by the value of an inner Dictionary using LINQ. Any thoughts?

Comment: Define "value of an inner Dictionary".

Comment: I believe he wants it alphabetically, based on the value of the Dictionary<string, string>

Comment: What does it mean to sort a Hash table?

Comment: Please give more information about what you want. Dictionaries aren't usually inherently sorted. What do you mean by "the value of the inner dictionary value" in the first place? An example of the data involved would be useful too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean you want all values, sorted by the inner value?

```
from outerPair in outer
from innerPair in outerPair.Value
orderby innerPair.Value
select new {
    OuterKey = outerPair.Key,
    InnerKey = innerPair.Key,
    Value = innerPair.Value
};
```

Comment: psychic debugging in action ;-p